# Listen to immediate change in input of ui:inputText Lightning component

Tags: lightning, event

I used this to create search input:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="search" label="" placeholder="Search By Name"
                  class="slds-input inputClass"
                  labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                  value="" change="{!c.searchChange}" updateOn="keyup"
                  required="false"/>
```

the problem is that searchChange function is fired only after press Enter
I want it to be fired while writing( while content is changing )
please help

Answer (score 1):

Use **Keyup** instead of **change** .**by using keyup event is fired whenever you releases keyboard key**

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="search" label="" placeholder="Search By Name"
                  class="slds-input inputClass"
                  labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                  value="" keyup="{!c.searchChange}" updateOn="keyup"
                  required="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried but same, it fired only on enter

Comment: change the edited code in your question @sundus

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyUp but inside in the div tag, I using it, and it works just fine:

```
<div onkeyup="{! c.handleSearchContact }">
<lightning:input
    aura:id="contactNameSearch"
    label="Search Contact"
    isLoading="{! v.issearching }"
    type="search"
    onclick="{!c.clearContactDataTable}"
/>
```

The "handleSearchContact" method is to handle the keyup.
And the "clearContactDataTable" method, it when clicking on (x).